# Parsing two XML file and save into one xml file

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have two XML files that I have to combine to one. I have no control over the XML files.

First XML looks like:

```
<Make>
  <cid>xxx</cid>
  <cname>xxx</cname>
</Make>
<Make>
  <cid>xxx</cid>
  <cname>xxx</cname>
</Make>
...
```

The second XML needs the 'cid' from the first to parse. Second XML looks like:

```
<Models>
  <Model>
    <mid>xxx</mid>
    <model>xxx</model>
    <rem>xxx</rem>
  </Model>
  <Model>
    <mid>xxx</mid>
    <model>xxx</model>
    <rem>xxx</rem>
  </Model>
 ...
</Models>
```

I can parse the two files and put them in a table. But I don't know how to save it as a XML file. The code for the table is:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://url-to-pars-xml-file';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 

echo '<table border="1" ><tbody><tr><td>cid</td><td>cname</td><td>mid</td><td>model</td>   <td>rem</td></tr>';

foreach ($xml as $cname):
$cid = $cname->cid;
$cname = $cname->cname;

//get models
$url2 = 'http://second-url-to-pars-xml-file?cid='.$cid;
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file($url2); 

//info from model
foreach ($xml2 as $rem):
    $mid = $rem->mid;
    $model = $rem->model;
    $rem = $rem->rem;

        $r ='<tr>';
        $r .='<td>'.$cid.'</td>';
        $r .='<td>'.$cname.'</td>';
        $r .='<td>'.$mid.'</td>';
        $r .='<td>'.$model.'</td>';
        $r .='<td>'.$rem.'</td>';
        $r .='</tr>';

        echo $r;

endforeach;
endforeach;

echo '</tbody></table>';

?>
```

Maybe I can save the table to an XML, but I think there must be a better way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the real [DOM](http://php.net/dom), then you can insert nodes from one tree into the other tree, then a simple `->save()`-type call produces your merged document.

Comment: @MarcB amles is working with XML, the table is just for display.  SimpleXML is a fine solution.

Comment: @cincodenada: "don't know how to save it as an xml file". simple xml is simple for a reason... merging two disparate xml documents is not what it's for.

Comment: Ah, true, depends on how complicated the merging is.  SimpleXML can still save out just fine though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need the final structure to look like, but in the inner loop, just combine them together with things like addChild()

```
$xml2->model->addChild('cid',$cid);
```

(e.g. If you just wanted to add the `cid` to each `Model` block) and then re-save it wherever you want:

```
$xml2->saveXML($save_destination);
```

My code is off-the-cuff and untested, but that's the basics.  Read up on [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for details, particularly [addChild](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) and [saveXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)

*Note: saveXML is just an alias for asXML, but I think it is clearer to use the former in this case.*

**Edit:** As @MarcB pointed out, if you want to do more complicated merging, you'd be better off doing a similar flow using the more powerful [DOM](http://php.net/dom) class to load and manipulate your XML, so you can copy/append nodes between files.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have to use DOM, this was just an short example, it's more complicated than this. I'm new to this so I will search for DOM and how to use it!